# How to send data over the URL to the Home Controller using ajax in Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to send data using ajax over the url to my home controller but I am getting a 404 error.

1.You can send multiple authors or genres Ids by selecting from a list got from the show add book.

2.You can send a Author by entering his details and adding a author

3.You can send a Genre by entering the details and adding a new the genre

4.You can select one publisher either from the list or my entering the details and creating a new publisher.

The above code works.
There is only a problem with receiving the data at the controller.
I can seed the data I entered on the link in the console error.

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addBook/"+authorName+"/"+genreName+"/"+bookTitle+"/"+publisherName+"/"+publisherAddress+"/"+publisherPhone+"/"+author+"/"+genre+"/"+publisherId
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $('#result').html(msg + "<br/>");
});
```

Home controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addBook/{authorName}/{genreName}/{bookTitle}/{publisherName}/{publisherAddress}/{publisherPhone}/{author}/{genre}/{publisherid}", method = { RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody String addBook(@PathVariable (value="authorName") String authorName,@PathVariable(value="genreName") String genreName,@PathVariable(value="bookTitle") String bookTitle ,@PathVariable(value="publisherName") String publisherName ,@PathVariable(value="publisherAddress") String publisherAddress ,@PathVariable(value="publisherPhone") String publisherPhone ,@PathVariable(value="author[]") String authorIds[] ,@PathVariable(value="genre[]") String[] genreIds ,@PathVariable(value="publisherid") String publisherId , Locale locale, Model model) {          
//Add Book code
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not getting what is the problem you are running into?

Comment: I am getting an error that the link an not be found. I have the link to it on the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
function statusFun()
{

    var x = document.getElementById("statusDropdown");
    alert(x.options[x.selectedIndex].value);

    var client = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    var htm = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "categorylist.php",
    data: "client="+client,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(htm)
    {
        alert(htm);
        $("#catid").html(htm);
        return true;
        // Uncomment the following line in your application
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("test1");
        $("#clientdetails").html("no result found");

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some context to your answer. Code only does not fulfill SO standards. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer